# CSS media query not working in Rails mailer template

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Does media query really not working in email template?
I have simple test template and a query **BUT** can't make it work.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>Report</title>

      <style media="screen">      
        @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
          h1.temp{display: block !important} //testing & not working....
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#f6f6f6">
      <h1 class="temp" style="display: none">Show Me in Mobile Device</h1>
      <%= yield %>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What browser/app are you testing it?

Comment: Hi @Roy i'm testing with Gmail app, as well as it's smtp configurations in Rails.

Comment: actionmailer put any media-query together. Just inspect your item in Gmail in browser.

Sent the same template via mutt(terminal email client) and rails. It works well via mutt. 

don't know yet how to deal with that

Comment: found own issue. I used old version of roadie gem. It squashes all media together. new one already recognizes media and skips to inline media with `min-with` or `max-with` additional options

Answer (score 0):

I used 'premailer-rails' gem and it works for me. This [tutorial](https://hackernotes.io/a-production-ready-rails-5-email-workflow-with-mailer-previews-premailer-and-activejob/) shows example.

Comment: Hi @olucube i tried but media query still didn't worked :(

Comment: so how are you testing it?

Comment: i set smtp (gmail) configuration in my Rails app, then check the sent mail to may account via browser & android phone

Comment: can you share your app\views\mailer\<mailer_view_template>.html.erb and and the app\views\layout\<email_view_tempate>.html.erb or the codes that have to do with sending the email here?  the style may be overwritten somewhere in your codes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194520/discussion-between-aldrien-h-and-olucube-com).